# Add value of an integer column and a datetime column and compare to current date

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three fields, namely `id` (Primary Key), `start_date` (Date) and `no_of_days` (Int). I need to fetch the results from this table in such a way that after adding `no_of_days` days to `start_date` the resultant date should be less than the current date.

For example, if we have this row in table

```
id     start_date    no_of_days
8      2011-08-19       10
```

If we add 10 (`no_of_days`) to 2011-08-19 (`start_date`) then the resultant date will be 2011-08-29 and it is also less than current date so this entry should be fetched.

How can I do this using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  start_date + INTERVAL no_of_days DAY < CURRENT_DATE
```

Or even better, an equivalent query which can use an index on the `start_date` column by rearranging:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  start_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL no_of_days DAY
```

Comment: The query I wrote is correct. Yours is overly verbose and uses unnecessary functions (extracting the date portion of an expression which is already a date). Why are you answering your own question in a comment?

Comment: Your answer is also significantly slower as it can't make use of any indexes.

Comment: Thank You for your answer Dan, I have removed my comment. Your reply worked. Thanx!